# What is the best way to display data in a template in Django?

Tags: django, templates, model

Given the below model and view, for any given club I am trying to display that club's available courts ("court") and available times ("avail_time") in the template.  I am having trouble doing this.

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Club(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.establishment

class Available(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    court = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    avail_time = models.DateTimeField('available time')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.court

class Taken(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    court = models.ForeignKey(Available)
    taken_time = models.DateTimeField('taken time')
    userid = models.EmailField(max_length = 75)
```

View:

```
def avail_times(request, club_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Club,pk=club_id)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/avail_times.html', {'club':p})
```

Template:

```
{% for court in club.court_set.all %}
{{court.court }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't seem to have a Court model, so I'm not sure why you're trying to call `court_set.all`. You could use `club.available_set.all` to show the list of Available instances for that club, which might be what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to set up your models appropriately. Clubs have Courts and Courts have Available Times. Clubs don't have Available Times, which is how you have it set up now. Further, "taken" is a *status* of an available time; it shouldn't be a model itself. Try something like:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.establishment

class Court(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='courts')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CourtTime(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE = 0
    TAKEN = 1
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (AVAILABLE, 'Available'),
        (TAKEN, 'Taken'),
    )

    court = models.ForeignKey(Club, related_name='times')
    time = models.DateTimeField('available time')
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_CHOICES[AVAILABLE])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.court
```

Then, I would suggest a custom manager on `CourtTime` to return available/taken querysets:

```
class CourtTimeQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def available(self):
        return self.filter(status=CourtTime.STATUS_CHOICES[CourtTime.AVAILABLE])

    def taken(self):
        return self.filter(status=CourtTime.STATUS_CHOICES[CourtTime.TAKEN])

class CourtTimeManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return CourtTimeQuerySet(self.model)

    def available(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().available(*args, **kwargs)

    def taken(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().taken(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, add it to your model:

```
class CourtTime(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = CourtTimeManager()
```

With all that in place, you can just do the following in your template:

```
{% for court in club.courts.all %}
    <h2>{{ court.name }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for time in court.times.available %}
        <li>{{ time|date:"m/d/Y g:i A" }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```